# Why is the Dirichlet Process not a completely random measure?

Tags: dirichlet-process, measure-theory

A completely random measure assigns independent mass to nonintersecting subsets.  I cannot figure, however, how the Dirichlet Process does not qualify as a CRM?  Aren't the atoms all independent from each other?

Comment: The mass of the atoms sum to 1, so they're not independent.

Comment: In particular, masses are negative correlated due to the constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by @marmle, the DP is not a completely random measure, as it has the constraint that the mass of the atoms must sum to one.  Where as the Beta Process and Gamma Process there are no constraints.